# Play! Framework - Passing Map to another public static method in same controller

Tags: java, playframework

The external route hits this method in a controller:

```
public static void externalRouteHit() {
  Map<String, String> myParams = request.params.allSimple();
  redirectedRoute(myParams);
}
```

Then, I try and pass the Map to another method in same controller, but it is null.

```
public static void redirectedRoute(Map<String, String> myParams) {
  if (myParams == null)
    Logger.info("WTF");

}
```

I can pass a string or boolean fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: myParams is not null inside `externalRouteHit()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call another public static void method from one of your controllers without play creating a redirect, you'll have to annotate the method with @Util

Example:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {


  public static void index(){
    Map xyz = ....;

    helperMethod(xyz);

  } 

  @Util
  public static void helperMethod(Map map){
    /// do stuff
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers, when a Play action  handles a Map parameter, it expects a specific format for the query parameters:

> Play also handles the special case of binding a Map
>   like this:
>
> > public static void show(Map client) {
> >        …
> >     }
>
> A query string like the following:
>
> > ?client.name=John&client.phone=111-1111&client.phone=222-2222
>
> would bind the client variable to a map with two elements. 
>   The first element with key name and value John, and the second 
>   with key phone and value 111-1111, 222-2222.

In other words, you have to use specially formatted, named query parameters.  What you want is instead to pass along all the query parameters.

Here's a working example.  It seems verbose, but it works.  Try hitting /application/externalRouteHit?color=red&size=XS.

```
public class Application extends Controller {                                                               

    public static void externalRouteHit() {                                                                 
        Map<String, Object> myParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();                                       
        for (String key : params.allSimple().keySet()) {                                                    
            if (!key.equals("body")) {                                                                      
                myParams.put(key, params.allSimple().get(key));                                             
            }                                                                                               
        }                                                                                                   
        redirect(Router.reverse("Application.redirectedRoute", myParams).url);                              
    }                                                                                                       

    public static void redirectedRoute() {                                                                  
        renderText("color = " + params.get("color") + ", size = " + params.get("size"));                    
    }                                                                                                       
}
```

Comment: This is a really good example.  I will try it out and +1 if the solution works!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the redirect is a true HTTP redirect (302), so will produce an HTTP request from the URL to the action name, and the Map will be attempted to convert to form part of the URL.

I guess the conversion from or to the Map is failing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass request parameters with redirect, you might want to simply use: params.flash(), it will store all params in cookie and they will be available in called controller (and template) through "flash" variable.

As of Map, it should work, documentation at http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers specificly tells:

> Play also handles the special case of binding a Map
>   like this:
>
> public static void show(Map client) {
>       … }

you might want to check which type is exactly returned by request.params.allSimple(), maybe it requires some special map implementation.